# Can I use PostgreSQL function in join?

Tags: postgresql

Can I use PostgreSQL function in join? also can I use cursor function in join?
actually this is what I want

```
Select m.* from Medication m
Left Join public.GetResidentMedications(, , , , , ,) f on f.Id= m.Id
```

same with the cursor functions?

**Below is my function which is a cursor function and I want to join it **

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public."GetResidentMedications" (
  ref refcursor,
  _alfid integer,
  _residentid integer,
  _types varchar,
  _limits integer,
  _offsets integer
)
RETURNS refcursor AS
$body$
BEGIN
  open ref for 
    --  select * from public."GetResidentMedications"('refcursor', 25, 331, '' , 20, 1)
    with cte AS (
       select m."Id" 
       from   public."Medication" m  
       where m."AlfId" = _AlfId
            and (m."ResidentId" = _ResidentId or coalesce (_ResidentId, 0) = 0)
            and 1 = (
            
                case when 
                    'IsVerified' = ANY ('{IsVerifiedsss, IsVerifieds}') and m."IsVerified" = true then 1 else 0 end
            )
    )
    select * from  (
       table  cte order  BY "Id"  limit  _limits offset _offsets
    ) sub
    Left join (select count("Id") from cte) c(TotalRecords) on true;
  
  return ref;                                                       
END;
$body$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
VOLATILE
CALLED ON NULL INPUT
SECURITY INVOKER
PARALLEL UNSAFE
COST 100;
```

is it possible to do it?

Comment: is it good performance wise

Comment: what is meant by this ***functionname() is a set returning function ***?.
sorry I am new to postgres. can you please short example?

Comment: I have edited my question and added function

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but: you should really avoid those dreaded quoted identifiers. They are much more trouble than they are worth it. https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don%27t_Do_This#Don.27t_use_upper_case_table_or_column_names

Comment: `'IsVerified' = ANY ('{IsVerifiedsss, IsVerifieds}') ` makes no sense - that will always evaluate to `false`

Comment: its under development and is hardcoded. I will replace with actual values

Comment: Then you can simplify the the whole `and 1  = (...)` with `and ('....' = ANY ('{IsVerifiedsss, IsVerifieds}') and m."IsVerified")`

Comment: ok thanks. I will follow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your function a set-returning function by defining it as "returns table (...)". The ref cursor is not needed.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public."GetResidentMedications" (
  _alfid integer,
  _residentid integer,
  _types varchar,
  _limits integer,
  _offsets integer
)
RETURNS table (id integer, ... other columns ... )
as
$body$
    with cte AS (
       select m."Id" 
       from   public."Medication" m  
       where m."AlfId" = _AlfId
            and (m."ResidentId" = _ResidentId or coalesce (_ResidentId, 0) = 0)
            and 1 = (
            
                case when 
                    'IsVerified' = ANY ('{IsVerifiedsss, IsVerifieds}') and m."IsVerified" = true then 1 else 0 end
            )
    )
    select * 
    from  (
       table  cte order  BY "Id"  limit  _limits offset _offsets
    ) sub
    Left join (select count("Id") from cte) c(TotalRecords) on true;
$body$
LANGUAGE sql
stable;
```

then you can use it like this:

```
select ...
from some_table
  left join "GetResidentMedications"(1,2,'bla',10,200) as g on g.id = ...;
```

Comment: ok but I use refcursor as I not want to specify many of columns as a return table

Comment: You **will** have to specify the columns at some point. If you don't do it in the function declaration you will have to do it _every time_ you use the function. Better do it once and don't worry about it.